# Count factors after a specific factor

Tags: r, count

I have a dataset including activities a, b, and c as follows;

```
User-ID    Date            Activity       Number of activity
1       03.04.2014         a              3
1       04.04.2014         c              2
2       05.06.2014         a              3
1       12.06.2014         b              2
1       06.10.2014         b              1
3       10.11.2014         a              3
1       05.11.2014         c              2
1       06.12.2014         a              1
2       06.12.2014         b              3
2       07.12.2014         a              4
2       07.12.2014         c              2
2       08.12.2014         a              1
3       08.12.2014         b              3
```

I would like to write a code which displays the sum of activities `a` and `c` for each user since the last activity `b`. For example; User-ID: 1 has activities "a" and "c"; in total 3 times after activity `b`. 
How can count the number of activities after a specified factor? (in here: since the last "b")

The expected result: 
User ID: 1   Total activity: 3
User ID: 2   Total activity: 7
User ID: 3   Total activity: 0

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Based on your example, the User ID 1 have only `c` and `a` after the last 'b' .

Comment: Hi, I added expected result. The  result: User ID: 1 Total activity: 3 User ID: 2 Total activity: 7 User ID: 3 Total activity: 0. For instance, user 2 has a, c and a activities since the last b activity, totally 7 activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try not to use variable names that contain spaces or hyphens unless you want to run into all sorts of problems.

```
df <- read.table(text='
User.ID    Date            Activity       Number.of.activity
1       03.04.2014         a              3
1       04.04.2014         c              2
2       05.06.2014         a              3
1       12.06.2014         b              2
1       06.10.2014         b              1
3       10.11.2014         a              3
1       05.11.2014         c              2
1       06.12.2014         a              1
', header=T)
```

Second, if you work with dates it's important to use an appropriate data type so that comparisons work.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Now to get the number of activities other than 'b' after the last 'b' for every user ID you can do:

```
sapply(split(df, df$User.ID), function(x)
    sum((x$Date > tail(sort(x$Date[x$Activity == 'b']), 1)) &
        (x$Activity != 'b')))
#1 2 3 
#2 0 0
```